# Create EXE from MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a Game Application using MVC 3 Web Application which is like this

[image]

the controller/action for this is Like \Home\Game

I want to know is it possible to convert this MVC app into an EXE file so, any user can run it on his PC. I know we can create EXE file for windows app, is it possible for Web  App?

Comment: You can create windows8 app :)

Comment: No, you cannot convert a MVC application to an executable. For executable, use WinForms or Console application.

Comment: I would do it allover again. I think you went the complete wrong way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly.

What you can do is use mono xsp to have a simple embedded webserver, which you can put into a .exe, which will then start a webserver on port xy, and open a web-browser with with

`http://localhost:xy/optional-virtual-directory/Home/Game`

you also need to localcopy that webserver-assembly to your web-app's /bin directory for it to work without any installation.

You'll also need to localcopy all necessary ASP.NET MVC-3 assemblies (because they are most-likely not installed by default).
And you need to add version 1.0.0 just in case somebody has installed MVC-4 locally.

And even then, it requires .NET framework 4.0 (or at least 3.5?) installed on the target computer.

Here a link to the latest stable-XSP sources:
http://download.mono-project.com/sources/xsp/xsp-2.10.2.tar.bz2

You can include the zipped web application as embedded resource and use a unzip-library to unzip it to a writeable directory, which you set as your webserver's root directory.

Make sure your unzip-library does properly unpack JavaScript files, because the microsoft-supplied windows-server windows-explorer-integrated-zip-handling utility does not properly unpack them (may depend on server version and security settings/policy).

```
static void Main()
{

    int iPort = 8080; // If admin rights it requires, wrong it is ;)
    iPort = 30080; // Damn !  I still no haz no admin rightz !


    string strBasePath = @"D:\UserName\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmbeddableWebServer\TestApplication";

    string strCurrentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strCurrentDirectory);
    //strBasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(di.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName, "TestApplication");
    strBasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(di.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName, "TestMvcApplication");

    //EmbeddableWebServer.cWebSource WebSource = new EmbeddableWebServer.cWebSource(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, iPort);
    Mono.WebServer.XSPWebSource ws = new Mono.WebServer.XSPWebSource(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, iPort);

    // EmbeddableWebServer.cServer Server = new EmbeddableWebServer.cServer(WebSource, strBasePath);
    Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer Server = new Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer(ws, strBasePath);

    Server.AddApplication("localhost", iPort, "/", strBasePath);
    Server.Start(true);


    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("\"http://localhost:" + iPort.ToString() + "\"");

    Console.WriteLine(" --- Server up and running. Press any key to quit --- ");
    Console.ReadKey();

    Server.Stop();
} // End Sub Main
```

I used this code to get around the missing locale-handling.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


namespace System
{


    public class Locale
    {
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(v=vs.80).aspx
        // #pragma warning disable 414, 3021

        public static string GetText(string message)
        {
            return message;
        }


        public static string GetText(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            return string.Format(format, args);
        }


        /*
        public static object GetResource(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }
        */


    } // End Class Locale


} // End Namespace System
```

---

**2019 Update:**

As per end-2019, you can use .NET Core 3.1, that way you can build a self-contained application, which the user can run without having .NET framework installed at all.

To build a self-contained .NET Core Application for x86 and x64:

```
dotnet restore -r win-x86
dotnet build -r win-x86
dotnet publish -f netcoreapp3.1 -c Release -r win-x86
```

Kestrel is an integrated web-server which you can use instead of Mono.XSP. 
With that, you can run your MVC/.NET-Core Web-Application on port xy (where xy is an unused port-number), and start a web-browser on `http(s)://localhost:xy`

Comment: @Anil: Added simple example code from my project :) By the way, you'll also need the sources of Mono.Posix and Mono.Security, and you may have to edit them a little.

Comment: If you need to install a web server on the client machine, **you're doing it wrong**. Like some major brands' univeral remote controls, which you program through a Java client to a Java webserver that gets installed on your machine and takes two minutes to start up on a high-end machine and hogs CPU and memory, all to display a wizard of four pages. Do not do this. Recreate the game in WinForms if you want to redistribute it as an executable. If you want to distrubite according to this answer, it will be ~ 50 MB large. Can't you just **host** the website somewhere and give people the URL?

Comment: All of you are Right, but i just want to know if there be any possible easy way to accomplish this without converting it to a win app...and @Quandary suggested a way...not sure how much it is feasible though..thanks all..

Comment: @CodeCaster: Actually, you don't need to install anything (except the required .NET framework) ! Works perfectly fine as non-administrator (I tested). And .NET isnt't Java. The webserver is up and running pretty instantly, how fast you get something in the browser depends on how long app_start takes, but usually well within 1 to 2 seconds.

Comment: I wanted to type "install or run" but the comment was full. It's not about performance, it's about the principle.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Principle doesn't pay for having to re-write an application. Besides, the future of WinForms is uncertain. Deployment size (including localcopy) will be bellow 10 MB in non-compressed state (already including a smaller application). If you compress it, it has 1.7 MB.

Comment: You're absolutely right, if you start writing a website when the specification ask for a desktop application, you might indeed work around your mistake by deploying or running a web server on the client machine and showing them the website instead of a form. That doesn't make this solution any less of a dirty hack. I do think it's nice of you to mention the possibility, but I don't think anyone shoulud ever use this in this way.

Comment: @CodeCaster, stop attacking strawmen. Web on desktop has valid uses and I don't believe you're adding anything useful to the discussion.

Comment: @staafl please point out the straw man I'm attacking here? The answer is about running a web server on a client, which in my humble opinion should be avoided at all cost, as it adds unnecessary dependencies and complexity to an application. A more useful answer would be: _"Just host the website on a web server and give your clients the URL"_. That is my stance in this discussion and frankly I think I made that clear about 24 hours ago. What is your point?

Comment: @CodeCaster, a web on desktop solution gives you a cross platform GUI that does not require a web connection and hosted server component.  I recently did something similar and my clients loved being able to use it via their browser, put bookmarks and the like. Now what is *your* point? It's a valid solution with its advantages and drawbacks to be sure, but that's up to the application writer. Virtual machines and interpreted languages also add dependencies and complexity, does it mean you only write native C?

Comment: @staafl "I did it" is not an argument. I never said it is not an option, but it only is after careful consideration and absolutely not the first, nor the only, let alone the best option. That is the only point I'm trying to make here. OP can read that, and take it or leave it out of his considerations, I don't care. If your goal is a cross-platform GUI, WinForms and Mono are something to look at.

Comment: any steps that would help a rookie to get started ??

Comment: @Thameem: In 2019, use ASP.NET Core, it has an integrated webserver called "kestrel". (Builder.UseKestrel)